# How to increment neighbor cells from a point in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, path, increment

I am trying to make my implementation of Lee's Algorithm more efficient, so far I am using a cubed loop to increment neighboring cells in my 2D integer array:

```
        for(int k = 1; k < g.length*2; ++k){
            for(int i = x0-k; i < x1+k; ++i)
                for(int j = y0-k; j < x1+k; ++j)
                {
                    if(i > 0 && j > 0 && i < g.length-1 && j < g.length-1)
                    {
                        if(g[x1][y1] != 0)
                            return true;    
                        if(g[i][j] == k && g[i+1][j] == 0){
                            g[i+1][j] = k + 1;
                        }
                        if(g[i][j] == k && g[i][j+1] == 0){
                            g[i][j+1] = k + 1;
                        }
                        if(g[i][j] == k && g[i-1][j] == 0){
                            g[i-1][j] = k + 1;
                        }
                        if(g[i][j] == k && g[i][j-1] == 0){
                            g[i][j-1] = k + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

Output of a 10x10 grid with points start(5,5) end(8,8):

```
00007670000
00076567000
00765456700
07654345600
76543234560
65432123456
76543234560
07654345600
00765456700
00076567000
00007670000
```

Is there a faster way of filling up the grid while also checking the value?

Comment: `x0` and `y0` are the start cell?

Comment: Yes, x0, y0 is the starting cell x1 y1 is the destination cell if changed I stop the incrementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know very little about this algorithm, but some material suggested that you choose your starting point as the point furthest from the center of the graph.

I ran your example, and code with this appended to the beginning:

```
if (d2 > d1) {
    startRow = startRow ^ endRow;
    endRow = startRow ^ endRow;
    startRow = startRow ^ endRow;

    startCol = startCol ^ endCol;
    endCol = startCol ^ endCol;
    startCol = startCol ^ endCol;
}
```

where `d2` and `d1` are the distances to the center from the end and start points, respectively.

I timed this over one million runs and received ~20% speed up.

Another option they suggested was to fan out from both the start point and the end point at the same time - but I wasn't sure what the stopping condition of that would be (since the target would begin at 1 in your code).

Comment: That is definitely something I could do to improve the current loop, however I was looking for something to replace the cubed loop entirely. I got some hints that it can be done using an array list, however I do not know how.

Comment: @user2266341 I'm not sure if that makes sense - an array list is basically just a dynamic array. Will the array ever have any boundaries (non-crossable points)?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly he meant by: "store the wave-front". From my point of view the wave-front is the front value of a incrementing integer, however I do not know what does he mean by storing it.

Comment: @user2266341 I guess you might want to clarify if he's talking about time efficiency or space efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are accessing your `g` array, `g[i][j]` for example, there are **two** under-the-hood [checks for boundaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds_checking). If boundary check is failed, `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown.

You can reduce number of boundaries checks by half.

Instead of using 2D array `g[W][H]` , you can use simple 1D array `g[W*H]`.
Then, instead of writing `g[i][j]`, you can write `g[i*W + j]`.